# How to add mobile number in twilio Caller IDs mobile number list using PHP?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying on Twilio free trial version. Here, I can sent sms to the mobile number which i've already verified in Twilio [caller ID](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified). Now, How could i add mobile number in this list with php code since i can't sent sms to unverified number in trial version.

I've searched many times but didn't find any solution to add mobile number on Caller IDs list through PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just verify the number?

Comment: Since i won't know all the users mobile number from beginning. When the user register first time than i want to add his number in Caller IDs list and later can sent sms on his mobile number.

Comment: I don't think Twilio permits that at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes may be. I've searched many docs like that in Twilio but didn't find any. If there is some way anyone knows! or, if similar things could be done by any other sites than that will be also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Verified caller Id can only be used for voice, not SMS. So you cannot set the from of an SMS to a non-Twilio number.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio

> We also allow verified phone numbers to be used as a caller ID on
> outbound calls (this feature not available for outbound messaging).

Comment: What i mean, i can sent sms to the number which is added in the [list](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified). Now, problem is i don't know all the numbers beforehand.So, i want add number via PHP file so that i can sent sms on that number after adding it. Is there any way to do it in Twiolio or any other similar site?